# Azure Add App Registrations you don't have Permission

Tags: azure, portal

I'm trying to register an application in Azure following these instructions in the link below.
I go to "App Registrations > New Registration" get the error "Access Denied You don’t have permission to register applications".
My user permission in the Azure Portal is Owner.

I can't find what permissions I need to set for my user so I can add a new app registration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Owner role is an Azure RBAC role and is not the same as Azure AD directory roles which you need to register apps.
Azure RBAC roles apply to subscriptions and resources within them. 
Azure AD tenants are above subscriptions.

Your Azure AD admin needs to give you at minimum Application Developer directory role.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had access to more directory's I was just on the wrong one.

So in my case that was my problem and by switching directory to the correct one where I had access my problem was solved.
First I checked that I was given the access mentioned above.